# serving two domains in apache SSL

Tags: asp.net, apache

My apache configuration is like

```
<VirtualHost informatyk2022a.online:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/informatyk2022a.online/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/informatyk2022a.online/privkey.pem
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass / https://informatyk2022a.online:7183/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://informatyk2022a.online:7183/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost dropdown.pl:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/dropdown.pl/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dropdown.pl/privkey.pem
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass / https://informatyk2022a.online:7183/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://informatyk2022a.online:7183/
</VirtualHost>
```

So I am redirecting from either [www.informatyk2022a.online](http://www.informatyk2022a.online) or informatyk2022a.online to

https://informatyk2022a.online

I have c# asp core service on port 7183. It works fine on domain.

I am also redirecting dropdown.pl to https://dropdown.pl:443

There on serving, it is proxy to

```
https://informatyk2022a.online:7183/
```

BUT BROWSER INSTEAD OF SHOWING WEB SITE SAYS CANNOT PROVE CERTIFICATE FROM

```
informatyk2022a.online
```

BUT I specify dropdown.pl certificate for apache to serve.

It is not serving website.

C# serves web site with certificate on secure port. It is apache that is not serving website with its own certificate but serving c# server certificate. How to make apache serving same secure service from two different domains?

I changed dropdown.pl 443 proxy to http port that c# uses but it did not help.

There is no way that I can serve same secure service on one port from two different domains.

|Apache fails to serve secure SSL certificate for dropdown.pl domain

Answer (score 0):

You can set in certificate Subject Alternate Name to be the hostname of second host.

For example the command cab be something like:

```
generate-certificate.sh -m <yourmail>  -d informatyk2022a.online -d dropdown.pl
```

to generate one certificate for both hosts.

Or command like:

```
certbot --apache --cert-name informatyk2022a.online -d dropdown.pl
```

Comment: i use letsencrypt. is there any command to specify two domains? I use sudo certbot certonly command

Comment: Am I right in understanding that it is not possible with apache to serve two domains for one service on one port?

Comment: @jacek, I edited my answer. And AFAIK there is no reason apache do not server two domains to one service backend,